# Подключение библиотек через Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Всем добрый день! Пытаюсь разобраться с ошибкой помогите пожалуйста.

В классе подключаются библиотеки

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

Что бы все заработало необходимо подключить две библиотеки

1) Apache HttpCore 
2) Apache HttpClient

Иду в Gradle в зависимости кидаю две строки

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.9'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
```

Андроид студио выдает что в классе библиотеки подключены но в Gradle Apache HttpClient подсвечивает красным. А при компиляции проекта возникает ошибка

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/blueprint.handlers'**

Помогите понять в чем тут проблема и как ее решить. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: добавьте `packagingOptions {exclude 'META-INF/blueprint.handlers'}`

Comment: Насколько я понял это не решает проблему а только маскирует ее.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что без этого файла жить нельзя, вы можете написать `packagingOptions {pickFirst 'META-INF/blueprint.handlers'}` или даже `merge 'META-INF/blueprint.handlers'`. Кроме того, изначальная ошибка в том, что `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` использовать [не стоит](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). Переходите на `OkHttp` или хотя бы на `HttpUrlConnection`